# Error al firmar xml con php para el sri

Tags: php, firma-digital

Hola soy de Ecuador y tengo una libreria en php y javascritp para firmar documentos xml, todo va bien con certificados de BANCO CENTRAL Y SEGURITY DATA, pero al intentar firmar con certificado de ANF me da el error (tipo de certificado no registrado), intente hacer unos cambios pero ahora me indica que la FIRMA NO VALIDA no se encontró el certificado root para la entidad emisora.

aqui esta la modificacion.

```
 include ('ejecutar.php');


$firmaFactura = $_POST['respuestaFirmarFactura'];
$validarContraseña = $_POST['respuestaValidarContraseña'];
$validarVigencia = $_POST['respuestaValidarVigencia'];


if(!empty($validarContraseña)){
  //Put Code

$file = fopen("recibe.txt", "a+");
fwrite($file, $validarContraseña .PHP_EOL);
var_dump($validarContraseña);


}
if(!empty($validarVigencia)){

//Put Code

$file = fopen("recibe.txt", "w+");
fwrite($file,$validarVigencia[0] .PHP_EOL);
fwrite($file, $validarVigencia[1] .PHP_EOL);
fwrite($file, $validarVigencia[2].PHP_EOL);
var_dump($validarVigencia);

//Put Code
}

if (!empty($firmaFactura)) {

$validarComprobante = $firmaFactura[0];
$autorizacionComprobante = $firmaFactura[1];

var_dump($validarComprobante);
var_dump($autorizacionComprobante);

//Put Code

}

$ruta_factura= 'http://localhost/Firma/2907202001100364051100110010020000000101234567818.xml'; //aqui se guarda el xml que se quiere firmar
$ruta_certificado= 'http://localhost/Firma/mauricio.pfx'; //el certificado
$contraseña= 'Renesan-02';
$ruta_respuesta= 'http://localhost/Firma/example.php';


$ejecutar = new ejecutar();
$domain_dir = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

 //Validar Contraseña del certificado
 //$ejecutar->validarContraseña($ruta_certificado,$contraseña,$ruta_respuesta);


//Validar Vigencia del certificado
 //$ejecutar->validarVigencia($ruta_certificado,$contraseña,$ruta_respuesta);


//Firmar Factura y enviar a SRI
 $ejecutar->firmarFactura($ruta_factura,$ruta_certificado,$contraseña,$ruta_respuesta);
```

Ejecutar php

```
  include ('app/includes.php');
  /** To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
 Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
* Description of ejecutar
*
* @author UESR
*/
class ejecutar {

public $conn;

//put your code here
public function __construct() {
    $this->conn = true;
    
}

//put your code here
public function validarContraseña($ruta_certificado, $contraseña, 
$ruta_respuesta) {

    $_SESSION['ruta_factura'] = $ruta_comprobante;
    
    //ejecuta funcion js obtenerComprobanteFirmado_sri en fiddle.js
    
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
    'try {
     validar_pwrd("' . $ruta_certificado . '","' . $contraseña . '","'.$ruta_respuesta. '")
     }catch(err) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
     }',
    '</script>'
    ;
    
    return true;
    //Tiempo limite
}

public function validarVigencia($ruta_certificado, $contraseña, $ruta_respuesta) {
          
    //ejecuta funcion js obtenerComprobanteFirmado_sri en fiddle.js
    
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
    'try {
     fechas_certificado("' . $ruta_certificado . '","' . $contraseña . '","' .$ruta_respuesta. '")
     }catch(err) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
     }',
    '</script>'
    ;
    return true;
    //Tiempo limite
    }

public function firmarFactura($ruta_factura ,$ruta_certificado, $contraseña, $ruta_respuesta) {
  


    //ejecuta funcion js obtenerComprobanteFirmado_sri en fiddle.js
    
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
    'try {
     obtenerComprobanteFirmado_sri("' . $ruta_certificado . '","' . $contraseña . '","' .$ruta_respuesta. '","' .$ruta_factura.'")
     }catch(err) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
     }',
    '</script>'
    ;
    return true;
    //Tiempo limite
}

}
```

include.php

```
include ('configuration.php');  ?>

<head> <scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="response">

</div>

</body>

<script src="<?php echo HOST; ?>/js/fiddle.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo HOST; ?>/js/forge.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo HOST; ?>/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo HOST; ?>/js/buffer.js"></script>
```

fiddle.js

```
function obtenerComprobanteFirmado_sri(ruta_certificado, pwd_p12, ruta_respuesta, ruta_factura) {

var response = [];
$.ajax({
    url: "src/leerFactura.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
              'ruta_factura': ruta_factura
           },
    context: document.body
}).done(function (respuesta) {

    window.contenido_comprobante = respuesta;
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", ruta_certificado, true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
        var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "application/x-pkcs12"});
        window.contenido_p12 = [oReq.response];
        console.log(window.contenido_p12)
        var comprobanteFirmado_xml = firmarComprobante(window.contenido_p12[0],
                pwd_p12,
                window.contenido_comprobante);

        $.ajax({
            url: "src/firma.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'mensaje': comprobanteFirmado_xml
            },
            context: document.body
        }).done(function (respuesta) {

            service = 'Validar Comprobante';
            xmlDoc = $.parseXML(window.contenido_comprobante),
                    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
                    $claveAcceso = $xml.find("claveAcceso");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "src/services/validarComprobante.php",
                data: {
                    'service': service, 'claveAcceso': $claveAcceso.text()
                },
                context: document.body
            }).done(function (respuestaValidarComprobante) {


                respuesta = decodeURIComponent(respuestaValidarComprobante);
                respuesta = respuesta.toString();
                var validar_comprobante = respuestaValidarComprobante;

                if (/RECIBIDA/i.test(respuesta) || /CLAVE ACCESO REGISTRADA/i.test(respuesta)) {
                    service = 'Autorizacion Comprobante';
                    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(window.contenido_comprobante),
                            $xml = $(xmlDoc),
                            $claveAcceso = $xml.find("claveAcceso");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "src/services/autorizacionComprobante.php",
                        data: {
                            'service': service, 'claveAcceso': $claveAcceso.text()
                        },
                        context: document.body
                    }).done(function (respuestaAutorizacionComprobante) {

                        var autorizacion_comprobante = respuestaAutorizacionComprobante;
                        response[0] = validar_comprobante;
                        response[1] = autorizacion_comprobante;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: ruta_respuesta,
                            data: {'respuestaFirmarFactura': response},
                            context: document.body
                        }).done(function (respuesta) {
                            //Respuesta enviada
                        });

                    });
                } else {
                    response[0] = validar_comprobante;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: ruta_respuesta,
                        data: {'respuestaFirmarFactura': response},
                        context: document.body
                    }).done(function (respuesta) {
                        //Respuesta enviada
                    });
                }

            });
        });
    }
    oReq.send();
}
);
}

function fechas_certificado(ruta_certificado, mi_pwd_p12, ruta_respuesta) {

var response = [];

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", ruta_certificado, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
    var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "application/x-pkcs12"});
    window.contenido_p12 = [oReq.response];
    var arrayUint8 = new Uint8Array(window.contenido_p12[0]);
    var p12B64 = forge.util.binary.base64.encode(arrayUint8);
    var p12Der = forge.util.decode64(p12B64);
    var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Der);
    var p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, mi_pwd_p12);
    var certBags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag})
    var cert = certBags[forge.oids.certBag][0].cert;
    //Validar Fecha de vencimiento del p12
    var fechaInicio = cert.validity['notBefore'];
    var fechaFin = cert.validity['notAfter'];
    var response = [];
    response[0] = fechaInicio;
    response[1] = fechaFin;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "src/validarFechaCertificado.php",
        data: {
            'fechaInicio': fechaInicio,
            'fechaFin': fechaFin
        },
        context: document.body
    }).done(function (respuesta) {
        response[2] = respuesta;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ruta_respuesta,
            data: {'respuestaValidarVigencia': response},
            context: document.body
        }).done(function (respuesta) {
            return true;
        });
    });
}
oReq.send();
}



function validar_pwrd(ruta_certificado, mi_pwd_p12, ruta_respuesta) {

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", ruta_certificado, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
    var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "application/x-pkcs12"});
    window.contenido_p12 = [oReq.response];

    var arrayUint8 = new Uint8Array(window.contenido_p12[0]);

    var p12B64 = forge.util.binary.base64.encode(arrayUint8);

    var p12Der = forge.util.decode64(p12B64);

    var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Der);

    try {

        forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, mi_pwd_p12);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ruta_respuesta,
            data: {'respuestaValidarContraseña': 'Contraseña Correcta'},
            context: document.body
        }).done(function (respuesta) {
            return "contraseña valida"
        });

    } catch (err) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ruta_respuesta,
            data: {'respuestaValidarContraseña': 'Contraseña Invalida'},
            context: document.body
        }).done(function (respuesta) {
            return "contraseña invalida"
        });
    }
}
oReq.send();
}





 var contenido_p12 = null;

 function firmarComprobante(mi_contenido_p12, mi_pwd_p12, comprobante) {


var arrayUint8 = new Uint8Array(mi_contenido_p12);
console.log(arrayUint8)
var p12B64 = forge.util.binary.base64.encode(arrayUint8);
var p12Der = forge.util.decode64(p12B64);
var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Der);

var p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, mi_pwd_p12);

var certBags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag})
var signaturesQuantity = certBags[forge.oids.certBag];
var count = 0;
var positionSignature = 0;
var entidad = signaturesQuantity[0].attributes.friendlyName[0];
console.log('prueba')
console.log(certBags)
if (/BANCO CENTRAL/i.test(entidad)) {
    entidad = 'BANCO_CENTRAL';
    var certBags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag})

    var cert = certBags[forge.oids.certBag][1].cert;
    // issuerName
    var issuerName = 'CN=AC BANCO CENTRAL DEL ECUADOR,L=QUITO,OU=ENTIDAD DE CERTIFICACION DE INFORMACION-ECIBCE,O=BANCO CENTRAL DEL ECUADOR,C=EC';
}

 else if (/ANF ECUADOR/i.test(entidad)) {
    entidad = 'ANF_ECUADOR';
    // get bags by type
    var certbags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag});
    // bags are key'd by bagType and each bagType key's value
    // is an array of matches (in this case, certificate objects)
    var cert = certbags[forge.pki.oids.certBag][0];
  // issuerName
  var issuerName = 'O=ANFAC Autoridad de Certificacion Ecuador CA,OU=ANF Autoridad Raiz Ecuador,C=EC,CN=ANF Ecuador CA1,2.5.4.5=#130d31373932363031323135303031';
  }
  /* //else if (/SECURITY DATA/i.test(entidad)) {
  //      entidad = 'SECURITY_DATA';
  //    var contador = 0;
  //  var max = 0;
    //var attributes_array=[];
    //certBags[forge.oids.certBag].forEach(function (entry) {
      //  var bag = entry.cert;
      //  var attributes = bag.extensions;
  //
   //          attributes_array[contador] = attributes;
 //        attributes_array.sort().reverse();
  //      max = attributes_array[0].length;
//
//          contador++;
        if (attributes.length >= 23) {
            cert = bag;
        }
    });

    certBags[forge.oids.certBag].forEach(function (entry) {
        var bag = entry.cert;
        var attributes = bag.extensions;
        if (attributes.length >= max) {
            cert = bag;
        }
    });



    // issuerName
    var issuerName = 'CN=AUTORIDAD DE CERTIFICACION SUB SECURITY DATA,OU=ENTIDAD DE CERTIFICACION DE INFORMACION,O=SECURITY DATA S.A.,C=EC';

  }*/
  else {
    entidad = "Tipo de certificado no registrado";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "error.php",
        data: {
            'error': entidad
        },
        context: document.body
    }).done(function (respuesta) {

    });
}
console.log(entidad)
//Validar Fecha de vencimiento del p12
var fechaInicio = cert.validity['notBefore'];
var fechaFin = cert.validity['notAfter'];


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "src/validarFechaCertificado.php",
    data: {
        'fechaInicio': fechaInicio,
        'fechaFin': fechaFin
    },
    context: document.body
}).done(function (respuesta) {

});

var pkcs8bags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag});

if (entidad == 'BANCO_CENTRAL') {
    var pkcs8 = pkcs8bags[forge.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag][1];
} else {
    var pkcs8 = pkcs8bags[forge.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag][0];
}

var key = pkcs8.key;
console.log(key)
if (key == null) {
    key = pkcs8.asn1;
}

certificateX509_pem = forge.pki.certificateToPem(cert);

certificateX509 = certificateX509_pem;
certificateX509 = certificateX509.substr(certificateX509.indexOf('\n'));
certificateX509 = certificateX509.substr(0, certificateX509.indexOf('\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----'));

certificateX509 = certificateX509.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '').replace(/([^\0]{76})/g, '$1\n');

//Pasar certificado a formato DER y sacar su hash:
certificateX509_asn1 = forge.pki.certificateToAsn1(cert);
certificateX509_der = forge.asn1.toDer(certificateX509_asn1).getBytes();
certificateX509_der_hash = sha1_base64(certificateX509_der);



//Serial Number
var X509SerialNumber = parseInt(cert.serialNumber, 16);

exponent = hexToBase64(key.e.data[0].toString(16));
modulus = bigint2base64(key.n);

comprobante = comprobante.replace(/\t|\r/g, "")



var sha1_comprobante = sha1_base64(comprobante.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', ''));


var xmlns = 'xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:etsi="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"';


//numeros involucrados en los hash:

//var Certificate_number = 1217155;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //1562780 en el ejemplo del SRI
var Certificate_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //1562780 en el ejemplo del SRI

//var Signature_number = 1021879;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //620397 en el ejemplo del SRI
var Signature_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //620397 en el ejemplo del SRI

//var SignedProperties_number = 1006287;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //24123 en el ejemplo del SRI
var SignedProperties_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //24123 en el ejemplo del SRI

//numeros fuera de los hash:

//var SignedInfo_number = 696603;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //814463 en el ejemplo del SRI
var SignedInfo_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //814463 en el ejemplo del SRI

//var SignedPropertiesID_number = 77625;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //157683 en el ejemplo del SRI
var SignedPropertiesID_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //157683 en el ejemplo del SRI

//var Reference_ID_number = 235824;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //363558 en el ejemplo del SRI
var Reference_ID_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //363558 en el ejemplo del SRI

//var SignatureValue_number = 844709;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //398963 en el ejemplo del SRI
var SignatureValue_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //398963 en el ejemplo del SRI

//var Object_number = 621794;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //231987 en el ejemplo del SRI
var Object_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //231987 en el ejemplo del SRI







var SignedProperties = '';

SignedProperties += '<etsi:SignedProperties Id="Signature' + Signature_number + '-SignedProperties' + SignedProperties_number + '">';  //SignedProperties
SignedProperties += '<etsi:SignedSignatureProperties>';
SignedProperties += '<etsi:SigningTime>';

//SignedProperties += '2016-12-24T13:46:43-05:00';//moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD\THH:mm:ssZ');
SignedProperties += moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD\THH:mm:ssZ');

SignedProperties += '</etsi:SigningTime>';
SignedProperties += '<etsi:SigningCertificate>';
SignedProperties += '<etsi:Cert>';
SignedProperties += '<etsi:CertDigest>';
SignedProperties += '<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1">';
SignedProperties += '</ds:DigestMethod>';
SignedProperties += '<ds:DigestValue>';

SignedProperties += certificateX509_der_hash;

SignedProperties += '</ds:DigestValue>';
SignedProperties += '</etsi:CertDigest>';
SignedProperties += '<etsi:IssuerSerial>';
SignedProperties += '<ds:X509IssuerName>';
SignedProperties += issuerName;
SignedProperties += '</ds:X509IssuerName>';
SignedProperties += '<ds:X509SerialNumber>';

SignedProperties += X509SerialNumber;

SignedProperties += '</ds:X509SerialNumber>';
SignedProperties += '</etsi:IssuerSerial>';
SignedProperties += '</etsi:Cert>';
SignedProperties += '</etsi:SigningCertificate>';
SignedProperties += '</etsi:SignedSignatureProperties>';
SignedProperties += '<etsi:SignedDataObjectProperties>';
SignedProperties += '<etsi:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#Reference-ID-' + Reference_ID_number + '">';
SignedProperties += '<etsi:Description>';

SignedProperties += 'contenido comprobante';

SignedProperties += '</etsi:Description>';
SignedProperties += '<etsi:MimeType>';
SignedProperties += 'text/xml';
SignedProperties += '</etsi:MimeType>';
SignedProperties += '</etsi:DataObjectFormat>';
SignedProperties += '</etsi:SignedDataObjectProperties>';
SignedProperties += '</etsi:SignedProperties>'; //fin SignedProperties

SignedProperties_para_hash = SignedProperties.replace('<etsi:SignedProperties', '<etsi:SignedProperties ' + xmlns);

var sha1_SignedProperties = sha1_base64(SignedProperties_para_hash);


var KeyInfo = '';

KeyInfo += '<ds:KeyInfo Id="Certificate' + Certificate_number + '">';
KeyInfo += '\n<ds:X509Data>';
KeyInfo += '\n<ds:X509Certificate>\n';

//CERTIFICADO X509 CODIFICADO EN Base64
KeyInfo += certificateX509;

KeyInfo += '\n</ds:X509Certificate>';
KeyInfo += '\n</ds:X509Data>';
KeyInfo += '\n<ds:KeyValue>';
KeyInfo += '\n<ds:RSAKeyValue>';
KeyInfo += '\n<ds:Modulus>\n';

//MODULO DEL CERTIFICADO X509
KeyInfo += modulus;

KeyInfo += '\n</ds:Modulus>';
KeyInfo += '\n<ds:Exponent>';

//KeyInfo += 'AQAB';
KeyInfo += exponent;

KeyInfo += '</ds:Exponent>';
KeyInfo += '\n</ds:RSAKeyValue>';
KeyInfo += '\n</ds:KeyValue>';
KeyInfo += '\n</ds:KeyInfo>';

KeyInfo_para_hash = KeyInfo.replace('<ds:KeyInfo', '<ds:KeyInfo ' + xmlns);

var sha1_certificado = sha1_base64(KeyInfo_para_hash);


var SignedInfo = '';

SignedInfo += '<ds:SignedInfo Id="Signature-SignedInfo' + SignedInfo_number + '">';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315">';
SignedInfo += '</ds:CanonicalizationMethod>';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1">';
SignedInfo += '</ds:SignatureMethod>';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:Reference Id="SignedPropertiesID' + SignedPropertiesID_number + '" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#Signature' + Signature_number + '-SignedProperties' + SignedProperties_number + '">';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1">';
SignedInfo += '</ds:DigestMethod>';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:DigestValue>';

//HASH O DIGEST DEL ELEMENTO <etsi:SignedProperties>';
SignedInfo += sha1_SignedProperties;

SignedInfo += '</ds:DigestValue>';
SignedInfo += '\n</ds:Reference>';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:Reference URI="#Certificate' + Certificate_number + '">';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1">';
SignedInfo += '</ds:DigestMethod>';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:DigestValue>';

//HASH O DIGEST DEL CERTIFICADO X509
SignedInfo += sha1_certificado;

SignedInfo += '</ds:DigestValue>';
SignedInfo += '\n</ds:Reference>';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:Reference Id="Reference-ID-' + Reference_ID_number + '" URI="#comprobante">';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:Transforms>';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature">';
SignedInfo += '</ds:Transform>';
SignedInfo += '\n</ds:Transforms>';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1">';
SignedInfo += '</ds:DigestMethod>';
SignedInfo += '\n<ds:DigestValue>';

//HASH O DIGEST DE TODO EL ARCHIVO XML IDENTIFICADO POR EL id="comprobante"
SignedInfo += sha1_comprobante;

SignedInfo += '</ds:DigestValue>';
SignedInfo += '\n</ds:Reference>';
SignedInfo += '\n</ds:SignedInfo>';

SignedInfo_para_firma = SignedInfo.replace('<ds:SignedInfo', '<ds:SignedInfo ' + xmlns);

var md = forge.md.sha1.create();
md.update(SignedInfo_para_firma, 'utf8');

var signature = btoa(key.sign(md)).match(/.{1,76}/g).join("\n");


var xades_bes = '';

//INICIO DE LA FIRMA DIGITAL
xades_bes += '<ds:Signature ' + xmlns + ' Id="Signature' + Signature_number + '">';
xades_bes += '\n' + SignedInfo;

xades_bes += '\n<ds:SignatureValue Id="SignatureValue' + SignatureValue_number + '">\n';

//VALOR DE LA FIRMA (ENCRIPTADO CON LA LLAVE PRIVADA DEL CERTIFICADO DIGITAL)
xades_bes += signature;

xades_bes += '\n</ds:SignatureValue>';

xades_bes += '\n' + KeyInfo;

xades_bes += '\n<ds:Object Id="Signature' + Signature_number + '-Object' + Object_number + '">';
xades_bes += '<etsi:QualifyingProperties Target="#Signature' + Signature_number + '">';

//ELEMENTO <etsi:SignedProperties>';
xades_bes += SignedProperties;

xades_bes += '</etsi:QualifyingProperties>';
xades_bes += '</ds:Object>';
xades_bes += '</ds:Signature>';

//FIN DE LA FIRMA DIGITAL

return  comprobante.replace(/(<[^<]+)$/, xades_bes + '$1');
 }

 function sha1_base64(txt) {
var md = forge.md.sha1.create();
md.update(txt);
//console.log('Buffer in: ', Buffer);
//return new Buffer(md.digest().toHex(), 'hex').toString('base64');
return new window.buffer.Buffer(md.digest().toHex(), 'hex').toString('base64');
}

 function hexToBase64(str) {
var hex = ('00' + str).slice(0 - str.length - str.length % 2);
return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
        hex.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" "))
        );
}

 function bigint2base64(bigint) {
var base64 = '';
base64 = btoa(bigint.toString(16).match(/\w{2}/g).map(function (a) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16));
}).join(""));
base64 = base64.match(/.{1,76}/g).join("\n");
return base64;
 }

 function p_obtener_aleatorio() {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 999000) + 990;
}
```

esta es la parte modificada en js.
con esta modificacion si firma el documento pero me da error de firma invalida.

```
if (/BANCO CENTRAL/i.test(entidad)) {
    entidad = 'BANCO_CENTRAL';
    var certBags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag})
    var cert = certBags[forge.oids.certBag][1].cert;
    // issuerName
    var issuerName = 'CN=AC BANCO CENTRAL DEL ECUADOR,L=QUITO,OU=ENTIDAD DE CERTIFICACION DE INFORMACION-ECIBCE,O=BANCO CENTRAL DEL ECUADOR,C=EC';
}   else (/ANF ECUADOR/i.test(entidad)) {
    entidad = 'ANF_ECUADOR';
    var certbags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag});
    var cert = certbags[forge.pki.oids.certBag][0];
  // issuerName
  var issuerName = 'O=ANFAC Autoridad de Certificacion Ecuador CA,OU=ANF Autoridad Raiz Ecuador,C=EC,CN=ANF Ecuador CA1,2.5.4.5=#130d31373932363031323135303031';
 }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué la etiqueta PHP si solo muestras código Javascript? Además, la información en la pregunta no tiene datos suficientes para sabe cuál es el error.

Comment: ya puse la mayoria de codigos pero segun yo hay que crear un tipo de certificado en el js que modifique para que sea compatible con la firma.

Comment: se debe tener en cuenta que hay dos pasos para recepcion y envio

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por compartir tu codigo me ayudo a resolver un problema similar.

Note q el Nombre de la empresa emisora no esta en todos los friendName de los Certbags, entonces lo solucione asi

```js
for (let z = 0 ;z<signaturesQuantity.length;z++){
    var entidad = signaturesQuantity[z].attributes.friendlyName[0];
    if (/BANCO CENTRAL/i.test(entidad)) {   

        cert = certBags[Forge.oids.certBag][1].cert;
      pkcs8 = pkcs8bags[Forge.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag][1];
       // issuerName
        issuerName = 'CN=AC BANCO CENTRAL DEL ECUADOR,L=QUITO,OU=ENTIDAD DE CERTIFICACION DE INFORMACION-ECIBCE,O=BANCO CENTRAL DEL ECUADOR,C=EC';
     break
    
    }else if(/SECURITY DATA/i.test(entidad)){
       cert = certBags[Forge.oids.certBag][0].cert;
       pkcs8 = pkcs8bags[Forge.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag][0];
       issuerName = 'CN=AUTORIDAD DE CERTIFICACION SUBCA-2 SECURITY DATA,OU=ENTIDAD DE CERTIFICACION DE INFORMACION,O=SECURITY DATA S.A. 2,C=EC';
       break
    }
}
```

por el momento no tengo un certificado .p12 de la ANF, pero supongo debe ser por ahi el problema, cuando lo consiga te cuento

Answer (score 0):

hola muchas gracias por el codigo fuente socializdo , a mi particularmente me sale el mensaje de firma invalida (firma y/o certificados alterados), respuesta del webservice sri. Su ayuda para resolver este problema  cabe señalar que la firma es con SECURITY DATA

Comment: Esto es más propio de un comentario que de una respuesta.